# Dockerized Wordpress is having Nginx Proxy Issues

Tags: customization, nginx, docker

I have a Dockerized Nginx Proxy that sits on my server.

One of my sites is a Docker-Compose Wordpress site. 
They are separate container and must remain that way.

**When I *update my Site Url* in the Settings I *can still log into my Admin* Dashboard, but I *cannot reach my actual site*. I receive a 502 Gateway Error from Nginx.**

Nginx Server Block:

```
   server{

        listen 80;
        server_name test.com;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8001;
        }
   }
```

Wordpress docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     build: ./wordpress
     ports:
       - "8001:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
     volumes: 
       - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini 
       - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini 
volumes:
    db_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container is binding port `80` to `8185` and your nginx proxy is pointing at port `8001` when it should be pointing at `8185`.

Comment: that was a typo in moving everything on to stackoverflow. they are bound to the same ports. if that was the problem i wouldn't be able to hit my site at all. i am able to hit the admin dashboard but nothing else.